# Question about 0x08059081

Tags: 12.04, security

currently doing some homework to improve my skills.

I tried to run a file by using gdb, but I encountered 2 errors as shown in the picture below.

[image]

```
0 0x08059081
1 0x080493c6
```

May I know what is #0 and #1? I would like to know what is this "0x08059081" is called. The name, address or reference something like that? And how can I know its value? Is there some way to determine its value or name etc?

Comment: That's the address where the value of a pointer value is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

0x08059081 is the content adress of a null pointer. You can find more informations on Wikipedia: [Segmentation fault example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault#Segmentation_fault_example):

> Because a very common program error is a [null pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_pointer) dereference (a read or write through a null pointer, used in C to mean "pointer to no object" and as an error indicator), most operating systems map the null pointer's address such that accessing it causes a segmentation fault.

For a better answer try to ask on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: Thanks.. The Wikipedia is useful. By any chance, do you know why my error did not show up which line they were?

Comment: @user169084 It's not easy to show up because a segmentation fault is not a compilation error, is an execution error. You need some debugging tools to do this.

Comment: Okay thank you.. is gdb one of the tools? Is there any other tool in ubuntu?